# cannot create directory Permission denied - even when using sudo

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, root

I am trying to install `gsl-2.5` - https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/. I have used the command `sudo ./configure && make && make install`, but still run into permission problems:

```
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libgsl.a
libtool: link: rm -fr .libs/libgsl.lax .libs/libgsl.lax
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgsl.la" && ln -s "../libgsl.la" "libgsl.la" )
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o gsl-randist gsl-randist.o libgsl.la cblas/libgslcblas.la -lm 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/gsl-randist gsl-randist.o  ./.libs/libgsl.so cblas/.libs/libgslcblas.so -lm
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o gsl-histogram gsl-histogram.o libgsl.la cblas/libgslcblas.la -lm 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/gsl-histogram gsl-histogram.o  ./.libs/libgsl.so cblas/.libs/libgslcblas.so -lm
creating gsl-config
creating gsl.pc
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5'
Making install in gsl
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/gsl'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/gsl'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/gsl'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/gsl'
Making install in utils
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/utils'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/utils'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/utils'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/utils'
Making install in sys
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/sys'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/sys'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/gsl'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/include/gsl’: Permission denied
Makefile:637: recipe for target 'install-pkgincludeHEADERS' failed
make[2]: *** [install-pkgincludeHEADERS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/sys'
Makefile:918: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sam/program_files/gsl-2.5/sys'
Makefile:963: recipe for target 'install
```

I am guessing that, for some reason, my root privileges don't include the  `/usr/local/include` directory. Does anyone know why this may be the case and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is Selinux running (command sestatus)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command

> ```
> sudo ./configure && make && make install
> ```

runs these three commands sequentially:

```
sudo ./configure
make
make install
```

Notice that only the first one has root privileges.

Typically you would run the configure/make stages as your own user account, assigning root privileges only for the final installation stage:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You can join these with `&&` if you're daring. Personally I prefer to leave the install stage as a separate activity that I apply only when I'm happy that the first two stages have completed not only successfully but also correctly.